# Remove Collection Index in Validation Message Name

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following validation using FluentValidation 8:

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Emails)
    .NotNull()
    .ForEach(x => {
        x.SetValidator(y => new InlineValidator<String>
        {
            z => z.RuleFor(u => u).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email is invalid")
        });
    });
```

When I insert an invalid email the name of the error is `"Emails[0]"`.

I would like to remove the index and simply use `"Emails"`.

Comment: What do you mean by `name of the error`? I'm asking because when I tried to reproduce with version 8.5 only place where I see `Emails[0]` is `PropertyName` on `ValidationFailure`. Tested with `new MyValidator(new MyObject{}).Validate`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add email prefix to your message use "{PropertyValue}" to your message:

```
public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Emails)
            .NotNull()
            .ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.SetValidator(y => new InlineValidator<string>()
                {
                    z => z.RuleFor(u => u)
                    .EmailAddress()
                    .WithMessage("{PropertyValue} : Email is invalid!")
                });
            });
    }
}
```

**Output:** "emailexample.com : Email is invalid!"

Adding prefix to default messages (built-in methods) can be done through extension:

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<string, string> AddMessagePrefix(
    this IRuleBuilderOptions<string, string> ruleBuilderOptions)
{
    ruleBuilderOptions.Configure(configurator =>
    {
        configurator.MessageBuilder = ctx =>
        {
            return $"{ctx.Instance}: {ctx.GetDefaultMessage()}";
        };
    });

    return ruleBuilderOptions;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Emails)
            .NotNull()
            .ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.SetValidator(y => new InlineValidator<string>()
                {
                    z => z.RuleFor(u => u)
                    .EmailAddress()
                    .AddMessagePrefix()
                });
            });
    }
}
```

**Output :** "emailexample.com: '' неверный email адрес."

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by **Overriding the Message**

Custom error messages can contain placeholders for special values such as `{PropertyName}` - which will be replaced in this example with the name of the property being validated. This means the above error message could be re-written as:

```
RuleFor(employee=> employee.EmailAddress).NotNull()
.WithMessage("Please ensure you have entered your {PropertyName}");
```

…and the value **EmailAddress** will be inserted.

Please check [Custom Validators](https://fluentvalidation.net/custom-validators) for more info

Comment: I think this will replace the actual message, not the `key` value of result.

Comment: What is the problem if you are getting the Email ID with an Invalid message, even if its replacing actual message
```RuleFor(employee=> employee.EmailAddress).NotNull()
.WithMessage("Email is Invalid {PropertyName}");```

Comment: It's not a problem, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it as per question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the way! There is an undocumented `OverrideIndexer` method which controls how the indicies are printed. We can make it to always return an empty string like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Emails)
    .NotNull()
    .ForEach(x => {
        x.OverrideIndexer((_, _, _, _) => string.Empty)
        x.SetValidator(y => new InlineValidator<String>
        {
            z => z.RuleFor(u => u).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email is invalid")
        });
    });
```

It works with the `RuleForEach` as well:

```
                r.RuleForEach(m => m!.names)
                    .OverrideIndexer((_, _, _, _) => string.Empty)
                    .NotEmpty()
```